# find an array with max size in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this in mongodb:

```
{
"pid":1,
"arr1":[2,3,4],
"arr2":[3,4],
"arr3":[1]
}
```

I want to get the array with max size using aggregate query. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What if there are multiple arrays with the same (max) size?

Comment: Then can I get only the max size??

Comment: You could try `db.collection.aggregate([ { "$project": { "maxSize": { "$max": [{"$size": "$arr1"},{"$size": "$arr2"},{"$size": "$arr3"}] } } } ])` but that should only get you the max size, not the array with the max size. You would need a further pipeline step, probably a `$redact` stage to get the array key.